# 100 days of Python - failing at reproduction

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm doing the 100 days of Python videos and I'm trying to reproduce the pytest example form https://github.com/talkpython/100daysofcode-with-python-course/tree/master/days/10-12-pytest/guess to make sure I understood it. But it doesn't work, even though I think I copied it 1-to-1 (when I run the code from the github, it works, for some reason).

The 3 files below are my reproduction - but the test fails unfortunately. Where is my error?

```
#scratch_module.py

def dumbfunc():
    return "I'm just a simple function."
```

and

```
#scratch.py
from scratch_module import dumbfunc


def myfunc():
    str = dumbfunc()
    return str + " HI, I'M MYFUNC!!!"


print(myfunc())
```

and

```
#test_scratch.py

from unittest.mock import patch

import scratch_module
import pytest
from scratch import myfunc


@patch.object(scratch_module, 'dumbfunc')
def test_myfunc(mock_method):
    mock_method.return_value = "MOCKED OUT! OK!"
    obs = myfunc()
    exp = "MOCKED OUT! OK! HI, I'M MYFUNC!!!"
    assert obs == exp
```

Comment: Common error: you need to patch where the object is used, not where it is defined. In other words, `@patch.object(scratch, 'dumbfunc')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, that worked! But I also managed to get it to work by changing in `scratch.py` the import: Instead of importing the function, I just `import scratch_module` and then assign `str = scratch.module.dumbfunc()`. So it seems the "patch object is used, not where it is defined" rule actually does not apply, bit something more subtle with the imports is happening. Could you please give me the full "story" of what is going on here?

Comment: That was an oversimplification. This comes down to the way names work in Python. In the first case, you imported dumbfunc into scratch, so the thing you need to change is what scratch defines as dumbfunc. In the second, you imported scratch_module, so the thing you need to change is what scratch_module defines as dumbfunc. Even so, it's still better to only change this within scratch itself, otherwise you're changing that reference for anything that calls scratch_module (which may not matter within a test, but still).